# Long path support in Net.Framework 4.7.2 and Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, .net-4.7.2, max-path, pathtoolongexception

To solve the problem of limiting paths to 255 characters, the following was done:

1. Windows 10 2004 includes "Enable Win32 long paths" in the "Local Computer Policy".
2. In the registry branch: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Control \ FileSystem` 
   set `LongPathsEnabled` = 1
3. Created a project in VS (Net.Framework 4.7.2)
4. Added manifest file (app.manifest) including `longPathAware`.
5. The fragment `<AppContextSwitchOverrides value = "Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling = false; Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths = false" />` is added to App.Config

But `PathToLong` exception still occurs when working with `System.IO`

Comment: maybe the manifest is invalid and the longPathAware entry is added at wrong place

Comment: As indicated in the source  https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN  ```<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
        <ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>```

Comment: have you also added the [supportedOS entry for Windows10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests#supportedos) to manifest?

Comment: Added only Windows 10. This does not work.

Comment: try .net 4.8 as it is latest classic .net framework version, .net 5 will be .net core based.

Comment: Does not allow to install 4.8, writes that it is already installed. But in the project properties, the highest available version is 4.7.2

Comment: You need to run Visual Studio installer and select 4.8 target pack

Comment: No. With 4.8 It also did not help. But they write that there is support for long paths since version 4.6.2 and higher